# finding the angle that the normal makes with the horizontal

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity, I would like to know if there is a way to calculate what angle the camera/headset is making with the horizontal.

I'm totally new to unity (I'm 13), so please go easy on me.

I was trying to calculate the angle like this:

```
float zAngle = (float)Mathf.Asin(headset.transform.forward.z);
```

My logic is this:  If the forward vector of a headset is the normal vector, it has a length of 1 (because it's a unit vector).

```
sin(angle) =       zComponent of forward vector
             ----------------------------------------------
             hypoteneuse =1 (our unit vector normal length)
```

angle = arcsin(z)

But when I rotate the camera (which is hooked up to the headset variable above), by 30 degrees along z axis, headset.transform.forward.z remains 1 (and it should be less than 1).

Right?  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you say "rotate along the z axis", do you mean you're rotating *around* the z-axis?  If you're calculating the angle that your camera's forward vector makes with the z-axis, then rotating around the z-axis won't change that angle, because your forward vector remains the same.  By rotating around the z-axis, you're tilting your head left or right while still looking forward.  So your forward vector doesn't change.

Comment: I understand!  It's the y component that I need, not the z!  Thank you!